# ViewController.swift Cannot invoke 'responseJSON' with an argument list of type '((_, _, _, _) -> _)'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have the following code in my `ViewController.swift`:

```
func OpenBarrier(){

    let parameters = [
        "username": keyStore?.stringForKey("loginUsername"),
        "password": keyStore?.stringForKey("loginPassword"),
        "api_key" : API.api_key
    ]


    Alamofire.request(.GET, "\(API.baseurl)/slagboom/open.json" , parameters: parameters)
        .responseJSON() { 
             (_, _, JSON, _) in

        println("JSON: \(JSON)")  
        }
}
```

and I get this error:

```
ViewController.swift:174:14: Cannot invoke 'responseJSON' with an argument list of type '((_, _, _, _) -> _)'
```

Comment: Which version of Alamofire are you using?  It works fine here with the last version version of Alamofire, Swift 1.2 and XCode 6.4

Answer (score 0):

Your `parameters` argument it should be `[String: AnyObject]?` instead of `[String : AnyObject?]`.

Fixing this error, you should be able to compile again.

Ensure your parameters variables exist. If not, the compiler is confused, and the error is not actually due to Alamofire. I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

i found it :)

```
//the parameters list was wrong

let parameters = [
    "username": keyStore?.stringForKey("loginUsername"),
    "password": keyStore?.stringForKey("loginPassword"),
    "api_key" : API.api_key
]

//when i cahnged it to the following it works, now to get around the keystore?

let parameters = [
    "username": "loginUsername",
    "password": "loginPassword",
    "api_key" : API.api_key
]
```